# Why isn't NSString answering to call by reference?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I'm trying to change a variable of NSString type by calling a method. But it doesn't work. I tried this very same method with othe types and it worked perfectly fine. Can you help me out there?

Interface:

```
- (void) changeNSString: (NSString *) stringToChange;
```

Implementation:

```
- (void) changeNSString: (NSString *) stringToChange{

    stringToChange = @"Test";    
}

- (IBAction)actionBla:(id)sender {

    NSString *myString = [NSString string];
    [self changeNSString:myString];
    NSLog(myString);            //Returns nothing or empty string

}
```

======================
Edit: thanks to the help of CrimsonDiego, here is a working solution. Though I still have a little understanding issue: why is there no type-error when assigning a NSMutableString to a NSString var?

Interface:

```
- (void) changeNSMutableString: (NSMutableString *) stringToChange;
```

Implementation:

```
- (void) changeNSMutableString: (NSMutableString *) stringToChange{

    [stringToChange setString:@"Test"]    
}

- (IBAction)actionBla:(id)sender {

    NSMutableString *myString = [NSMutableString string];
    [self changeNSMutableString:myString];
    self.myLabel.text = myString;           //Why is there no type error???

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning a new variable to a local variable within the function.

The local variable `stringToChange` references the same variable as `myString` at first, but when you assign @"Test" to stringToChange, it no longer references the original string.

The solution here would be to use `NSMutableString`, or have a class variable (or property) and use that instead of passing it to the function.

Comment: So I guess, the reason why the reference betweend the local variable `stringToChange` and `myString` (which is there at first) is destroyed is, that NSString is immutable?

Comment: It isn't because the string is immutable - the same would happen if you just replaced 'NSString' with 'NSMutableString' - what is happening is that `stringToChange` and `myString` are two separate variables that initially reference the same object. When you assign @"Test" to the `stringToChange` variable, you are *not* editing the old object. You are assigning a *new* object to the `stringToChange` variable, without changing the old one. If you wanted to use an NSMutableString, you'd simply say inside the changeNSString function: `[stringToChange setString:@"Test"]`.

Comment: I still have a little understanding issue: why is there no type-error when assigning a NSMutableString to a NSString var?

Comment: An NSMutableString is a subclass of NSString, ergo an NSMutableString **is** an NSString, just a specialized one.

Answer (score 3):

Your setting `stringToChange` as local in your function. Try the following:

```
- (NSString*) changeNSString: (NSString *) stringToChange{

    stringToChange = @"Test";
    return stringToChange;
}

- (IBAction)actionBla:(id)sender {

    NSString *myString = [NSString string];
    myString = [self changeNSString:myString];
    NSLog(myString);            //Returns nothing or empty string

}
```

Comment: This is actually another excellent method of doing this. Upvoted.

Comment: Sorta -- it doesn't actually *change* any of the strings.  It changes the references.  While this works, it is a bit inefecient.

Answer (score 2):

I am no expert on Objective-C but it seems to me that `stringToChange`, as in "normal" C, is a parameter that can contain a pointer to a string. The parameter is pass-by-value and thus, when you assign `@"Test"` to `stringToChange` you are actually only changing the local parameter `stringToChange` and not `myString`. If you want to change `myString` you have to change the parameter type to `NSString **` and pass `&myString` as a parameter instead.

Comment: This is technically absolutely correct, but it should be noted that as a matter of convention the pointer-to-pointer technique should only be used in very specific circumstances in Cocoa, and this isn't one of them.

Comment: I think that's not true, since all objects in Objective C are pointers.

Comment: That is why he said it was technically absolutely correct. It would work, true, but Cocoa conventions state that you should avoid behavior like this.